# Does the fuel pressure regulator ever go out of calibration?

Tags: fuel-system, vacuum

On GM 3800 SFI engine, does the fuel pressure regulator ever go out of calibration? My FPR does not leak, can I assume it is good? The fuel pressure rises with RPM and goes lower at idle. Is that all I need to see?

Answer (score 1):

Never assume anything because you'll usually find yourself wrong. You can easily test to see if the FPR is doing it's job by ... well ... testing it. Most fuel injected vehicles (and every GM one I'm aware of) has a Schrader valve located at some place on the fuel rail before the FPR which will allow you to plug a fuel pressure tester onto and give you an accurate fuel pressure reading. There's no guessing. No muss. No fuss. And definitely no assumptions.